# How can I take multiple (a lot) of inputs from a user and repeat code with each input the user gives? (Python)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, user-input

First, I apologize if I make/made any mistakes, or sound silly. I have only just started learning python about a week ago and I'm trying to build a web scraping program with the little knowledge I currently have. There may be some useless time.sleep functions and things, but I have changed and tested many things to get my script to work, so please ignore those things, unless there are critical errors in my code, or stuff I can improve.

So I have written this script using selenium with intent to take video links from the app "TikTok," and run them through a TikTok video downloader website to download these videos. I have successfully written a script that can be used with one link at a time. For example, the user inputs a link and the script opens the website, pastes the link, submits, and then downloads the video from the link.

I am wondering how I can turn this script into one where the user may input many many links, (up to 100) and repeat the downloading process until there are no more links. I would also like for my program to display the current link in use on the terminal, and say "Successfully Downloaded" every time a video is downloaded. My current script code is below. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
# imports
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# set chrome options
options = Options()
options.headless = False

# path of chrome webdriver
PATH= 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'

# print text and ask for user link
print('TikTok Auto Download Links BOT')
print('-' * 30)
link_url = input('Enter link to be downloaded: ')

# set browser driver and open window with select size
browser = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options = options)
browser.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get('https://snaptik.app/en-us')

time.sleep(1)

# find url box and paste user's input then submit
url_field = browser.find_element_by_id('url')
url_field.send_keys(link_url)
url_field.submit()

time.sleep(3)

# click download button
download_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="div_download"]/section/div/div/div/article/div[2]/div/a[1]')
time.sleep(3)
download_button.click()

# print successful for UI
time.sleep(3)
print('Download successful! ')

# wait before closing
time.sleep(3)

# close browser 
browser.quit()
```

Comment: You can use `while True:` and `break` when user accepts to exit else `continue`

Comment: Your final result will most likely depend on how the user is allowed to input data. Does this run in terminal only? Can he/she provide a list (or perhaps a file) of url's for you to handle? A loop over a list would be nice in my humble opinion. The method @JenilDave mentions will work as well, provided your user will manually enter all the URL's he/she wants.

Comment: Thank you for the provided information! I'll look into this a little bit more and try this out. And yes, this runs in terminal only and the user inputs links manually i.e. by copy pasting them from a text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# set chrome options
options = Options()
options.headless = False

# path of chrome webdriver
PATH= 'C:/Users/COUNT DEXTER/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe'

# print text and ask for user link
print('TikTok Auto Download Links BOT')
print('-' * 30)

set_download_limit = 100 #download limit
i=1 #counter
while i<=set_download_limit: #while condition
    link_url = input('Enter link to be downloaded: ')

    # set browser driver and open window with select size
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options = options)
    browser.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
    browser.maximize_window()
    browser.get('https://snaptik.app/en-us')

    time.sleep(1)

    # find url box and paste user's input then submit
    url_field = browser.find_element_by_id('url')
    url_field.send_keys(link_url)
    url_field.submit()

    time.sleep(3)

    # click download button
    download_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="div_download"]/section/div/div/div/article/div[2]/div/a[1]')
    time.sleep(3)
    download_button.click()

    # print successful for UI
    time.sleep(3)
    print('Download successful! ')
    i+=1 #increment counter, then return to loop

# wait before closing
time.sleep(3)

# close browser 
browser.quit()```
````

Comment: I was going to figure out how to write this myself but thanks for implementing it for me haha. It works but I seem to be getting an error. This error happens at random! Sometimes it will be on the first download, sometimes 2nd, or sometimes 10 downloads in! selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="div_download"]/section/div/div/div/article/div[2]/div/a[1]"}
  (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.89) I don't understand how It wouldn't locate the element only sometimes. Could this be explained?

Comment: That might be because in some websites, xpaths changes relatively. So I would recommend to locate to button using its `id` or `name`

Comment: Thanks for the info. I had to use xpath however because no other find_element functions were available in the HTML. It seems however that I fixed it by changing some of the time.sleep() functions. But now I'm wondering if there is a way I can have each download open in a separate tab rather than a new window every time?